# Genetic Algorithm for minimizing the Cost Function in Linear Regression

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, linear-regression, genetic-algorithm

I am training my dataset using a multivariable (say, 10) linear regression model. I have to choose the parameters but it results in overfitting. I have read that using the genetic algorithm for tuning my parameters we may achieve the minimum possible cost function error.

I am a complete beginner in this area and am unable to understand how the genetic algorithm can help in choosing the parameters using the parent's MSE. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: (1) how do you know you are overfitting? (linear regression overfitting sounds _very_ weird) (2) "minimum possible cost function error" is just overfitting. I suggest you read about and try to use regularization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_%28mathematics%29

Comment: @BlackBear 1. I meant that my test error is much higher than my train error. 
2. I want to tune my parameters so that I want to achieve minimum MSE in the test dataset.